# Use Selenium to click on a file link, store the html into a variable and download a specific filename with certainy text

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, download

Need assistance to complete the rest tasks:

1. Click and open the link under "SUMMARY"
2. Copy the new html link to a variable for future use.
3. Download the pdf into a folder

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\geckodriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
StockList = ['02192']
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchStockCode"))).send_keys(StockList[0])


wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "searchTitle"))).send_keys( "Announcement of Offer Price and Allotment Results" )


ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='slimScrollDiv']/descendant::tbody/tr[1]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(ele).click().perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class*='applyFilters']"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Announcement of Offer Price and Allotment Results").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below xpath :

```
a[rel='noopener noreferrer']
```

to click on link.

```
new_link_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[rel='noopener noreferrer']")))
var_new_link = new_link_element.get_attribute('href')
```

in case you wanna click on it, you can do it like :

```
new_link_element.click()
```

**Udpate :**

once you click on `Announcement of Offer Price and Allotment Results`, a new tab will be opened up,

so next you have to switch the driver focus like this :

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "SUMMARY"))).click()
```

Comment: What is this a[rel='noopener noreferrer']?

Comment: After running further :  driver.find_element_by_link_text("Announcement of Offer Price and Allotment Results").click()      how do I click further by choosing the right link, path under text "SUMMARY"

Comment: yes replacement of link_text, since text can be changed as you change the input

Comment: Think i missed your point here.  still not sure I can get to the link under "SUMMARY" which, if clicked, should open this  https://www1.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/sehk/2021/0714/9850114/2021071400030.pdf

Comment: ahh, got it looks like we have two tabs in place. I will update my code

Comment: Great stuff.   The completed one would add :  
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
new_link_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "SUMMARY")))
new_link_element.click()
var_new_link = new_link_element.get_attribute('href')